# Encode MPEG Movie via Javascript/Webbrowser?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, browser

I have created a script in JS which creates video frames as separate images, which I would like to encode to a video format (eg. MPEG-4). What would be the best way to do that? I considered using Node.JS and FFMpeg on the server, though I can't see why would anyone want to upload hundreds of 1080p images to the server solely for encoding and downloading again. How about a separate browser plugin? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest thing I saw is this - [Whammy: A Real Time Javascript WebM Encoder](http://antimatter15.com/wp/2012/08/whammy-a-real-time-javascript-webm-encoder/)
Some people tried to compile [ffmpeg with emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/issues/957) but I'm not sure about result

Comment: It looks like whammy uses webp which is a static image format similar to jpeg or png, so you're not going to get the type of compression you would get with a motion compression algorithm like mpeg4.

Comment: problem with the whammy.js is that it does not work on browsers which does not support webp format. you may be interested about this effort to make whammy a cross browser webm encoder of mine [cross browser whammy](https://github.com/imalhasaranga/whammy-cross-browser-demo)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that success was achieved here http://www.briangrinstead.com/blog/video-funhouse